# Problems trying to subscribe in a MQTT topic - Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, mqtt

I'm trying to subscribe in a MQTT topic with Angular 5, I'm using ng2-mqtt.
After creating my client i try to connect, and it's when the problems start. I'm getting this error: **AMQJS0012E Invalid type undefined for onSuccess**

Does anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


import {Paho} from 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

  client;

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('m2m.eclipse.org', 1883, 
    '_32fc96dd776142e6ba1a95116d09064f');

    this.client.connect({onSuccess: this.onConnected()})
  }

  onConnected() {
    console.log("Connected");
    this.client.subscribe("/cmd1234")
  }

 }
```

Here is my browser console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the return value `undefined`

```
this.client.connect({onSuccess: this.onConnected()})
```

You need to remove the `()` so that you assign the function

```
this.client.connect({onSuccess: this.onConnected})
```

You are using the `this` reference in the function.

```
onConnected() {
   console.log("Connected");
   this.client.subscribe("/cmd1234")
}
```

When you use the `this` reference make sure you use bind to ensure it persists.

```
this.client.connect({onSuccess: this.onConnected.bind(this)})
```

I wouldn't do any of the above. I would use a TypeScript anonymous function instead.

```
this.client.connect({onSuccess: () => this.onConnected() })
```

Comment: I did it, but then  I got : WebSocket connection to 'ws://m2m.eclipse.org:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. I just changed the host of MQTT server and did not passed a port, then every thing went fine

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('ws://iot.eclipse.org/ws','_32fc96dd776142e6ba1a95116d09064f');

   this.client.connect({onSuccess:()=> this.onConnected()})
   this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessage.bind(this);
```

}